# can't format javascript timestamp string toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
new Date().toLocaleString() --> "‎24‎/‎09‎/‎2015‎ ‎10‎:‎14‎:‎00‎ ‎PM"
new Date("2015-09-24 09:38:32.639").toLocaleString() --> "Invalid Date"
```

How can I format a date object from a timestamp in string format?

**SOLUTION:** At the end I got it fixed changing my date type in the server from DateTime to Instant, js will atomatically add zone offset automatically from a timestamp and will format the dates in the right way.

**NOTE:** I know this question is duplicated, however the solution proposed is different and may help other users to get a different approach to their code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myDate = "2015-09-24 09:38:32.639";

new Date(myDate.replace(/-/g,"/")).toLocaleString()
```

Now it's working fine

Comment: thanks for your quick response but this is not working for internet explorer edge...